Ring buffer writing same index 3x faster than incrementing index
I'm trying to learn about ringbuffers.
Inspired by the "ringbuffer-spsc" crate, I'm trying to modify it to a MPSC queue.
However, I encountered a performance difference I'm unable to understand.
Hopefully some of you can help me spot and explain what is happening.
The MPMRRingBuffer struct
pub struct MPMRRingBuffer<T: Clone, const N: usize> {
    buffer: UnsafeCell<[MaybeUninit<T>; N]>,
    idx_w: CachePadded<AtomicUsize>,
}


unsafe impl<T: Clone, const N: usize> Send for MPMRRingBuffer<T, N> {}
unsafe impl<T: Clone, const N: usize> Sync for MPMRRingBuffer<T, N> {}

impl<T: Clone, const N: usize> MPMRRingBuffer<T, N> {
    pub fn init() -> (MultipleRingBufferWriter<T, N>, MultipleRingBufferReader<T, N>) {
        assert!(
            N.is_power_of_two(),
            "RingBuffer requires the capacity to be a power of 2. {N} is not."
        );
        let rb = Arc::new(MPMRRingBuffer {
            buffer: UnsafeCell::new(array_init::array_init(|_| MaybeUninit::uninit())),
            idx_w: CachePadded::new(AtomicUsize::new(0)),
        });
        (
            MultipleRingBufferWriter {
                inner: rb.clone(),
            },
            MultipleRingBufferReader {
                inner: rb,
            },
        )
    }
}


pub struct MultipleRingBufferWriter<T: Clone, const N: usize> {
    inner: Arc<MPMRRingBuffer<T, N>>,
}

impl<T: Clone, const N: usize> MultipleRingBufferWriter<T, N> {

#[inline]
    pub fn push(&self, t: T) {
        // Let's increment the counter and let it grow indefinitely and potentially overflow resetting it to 0.
        let previous_write_idx = self.inner.idx_w.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);

        // Insert the element in the ring buffer
        unsafe {
            let item = &mut (*self.inner.buffer.get())[previous_write_idx & (N - 1)];
            let _ = mem::replace(item, MaybeUninit::new(t));
        };
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn push2(&self, t: T) {
        // Let's increment the counter and let it grow indefinitely and potentially overflow resetting it to 0.
        let _ = self.inner.idx_w.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);

        // Insert the element in the ring buffer
        unsafe {
            let item = &mut (*self.inner.buffer.get())[1];
            let _ = mem::replace(item, MaybeUninit::new(t));
        };
    }
}

pub struct MultipleRingBufferReader<T: Clone, const N: usize> {
    inner: Arc<MPMRRingBuffer<T, N>>,
}
impl<T: Clone, const N: usize> MultipleRingBufferReader<T, N> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn peek_newest_write(&self) -> Option<(T, usize)> {
        // Check if the ring buffer is potentially empty
        let idx = self.inner.idx_w.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        if idx == 0 {
            // No items yet
            return None;
        }

        let idx = idx - 1;
        let t = unsafe {
            self.inner.get_mut(idx).assume_init_ref().clone()
        };

        Some((t, idx))
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn peek_newest_write2(&self) -> Option<(T, usize)> {
        // Check if the ring buffer is potentially empty
        let idx = self.inner.idx_w.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        if idx == 0 {
            // No items yet
            return None;
        }

        let t = unsafe {
            self.inner.get_mut(1).assume_init_ref().clone()
        };

        Some((t, idx))
    }
}

Testing with 6 threads writing 500.000 i32 to the buffer(N=2048), push is 3-4x slower than push2.
On my MacBook Pro M1, push1 runs in 31.189 ms where push2runs in 8.9905 ms
Is it branch prediction issues, cache invalidation when an item is written to idx+1 or am I missing something else?.
NOTE: I am aware that push2 is not correct as a ring buffer. Its only to understand the performance difference
The benchmark with criterion:
const NUM_MESSAGES: usize = 524_281;
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 2048;
const WRITER_THREADS: usize = 6;

fn benchmark_push2(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("push2_channel", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            let (sender, receiver) = MPMRRingBuffer::<i32, BUFFER_SIZE>::init();
            let mut handles = vec!();


            for i in 0..WRITER_THREADS {
                let arc_sender = sender.clone();
                let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                    for j in 0..NUM_MESSAGES / WRITER_THREADS {
                        arc_sender.push2((i * j) as i32); // Send a message
                    }
                });

                handles.push(handle);
            }

            handles.into_iter().for_each(|f| f.join().unwrap()); // Wait for the thread to finish
            let a = receiver.peek_newest_write2();
            assert_eq!(a.unwrap().1, 524279);
            assert_ne!(a.unwrap().0, i32::MAX) // make sure value is not optimized away
        });
    });
}

fn benchmark_push(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("push_channel", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            let (sender, receiver) = MPMRRingBuffer::<i32, BUFFER_SIZE>::init();
            let mut handles = vec!();


            for i in 0..WRITER_THREADS {
                let arc_sender = sender.clone();
                let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                    for j in 0..NUM_MESSAGES / WRITER_THREADS {
                        arc_sender.push((i * j) as i32); // Send a message
                    }
                });

                handles.push(handle);
            }

            handles.into_iter().for_each(|f| f.join().unwrap()); // Wait for the thread to finish
            let a = receiver.peek_newest_write();
            assert_eq!(a.unwrap().1, 524279);
            assert_ne!(a.unwrap().0, i32::MAX) // make sure value is not optimized away
        });
    });
}


Given that push2 establishes no connection between idx_w and the buffer, its quite possible that the compiler writes to the 1 index once and then you're just left with the cost of the atomic increments. Seeing your testing code would help.

I've added the benchmark to the post

I have copied your code to the playground here and included two functions that reflect the task given to your thread::spawns:
#[inline(never)]
pub fn simulated_thread_push(i: usize, arc_sender: MultipleRingBufferWriter<i32, BUFFER_SIZE>) {
    for j in 0..NUM_MESSAGES / WRITER_THREADS {
        arc_sender.push((i * j) as i32); // Send a message
    }
}

#[inline(never)]
pub fn simulated_thread_push2(i: usize, arc_sender: MultipleRingBufferWriter<i32, BUFFER_SIZE>) {
    for j in 0..NUM_MESSAGES / WRITER_THREADS {
        arc_sender.push2((i * j) as i32); // Send a message
    }
}

From there you can analyze the generated assembly for each one. I won't assess push since it does mostly what you'd expect. I will assess the push2 variant though:
playground::simulated_thread_push2:
    pushq   %rax
    movq    %rsi, (%rsp)
    movl    $87380, %eax

.LBB2_1:
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    lock        incq    8320(%rsi)
    addq    $-10, %rax
    jne .LBB2_1
    imull   $87379, %edi, %eax
    movl    %eax, 132(%rsi)
    lock        decq    (%rsi)
    jne .LBB2_4
    #MEMBARRIER
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    callq   alloc::sync::Arc<T,A>::drop_slow

.LBB2_4:
    popq    %rax
    retq

From here we can see it is simply incrementing the idx_w in a loop until it does it 87380 times (524_281 / 6) and only after it is done it sets the buffer[1] value to the final i * j.
The compiler is able to do this because you have no synchronization around buffer. There is no data dependency on idx_w (as opposed to push) and Relaxed means the atomicity only affects idx_w and will not establish a "happens before" or "happens after" relationship with buffer. Since there is no synchronized side-effect on buffer in push2, the compiler can simply do the write once and thus does a lot less work than push. Do not use Relaxed if you intend for it to imply other side-effects.
To be clear, this is 100% undefined behavior (you have the potential for data-races everywhere) and contemplating the performance of wrong code is fool-hardy anyway. You have multiple other UB and soundness holes in your implementation (unconstrained Send/Sync, ABA-related issues).

Thank you for the answer. This was very insightful! My requirements/usecase for the ringbuffer is quite loose. I need to write data to the buffer, the exact order is not important. The only important part is that there are no race condition writing different values to the same index, unless the idx > N and we wrap around the buffer. Same goes for read_newest(). It does not have to be strictly the newest. Given these conditions, I believe push() and read_newest() with Ordering::Relaxed is OK to use in a Multiple-producer Multiple-reader case?

No, Relaxed is not sufficient. Without at least Acquire-Release semantics, a write to the buffer may never be visible on another thread. As a word of caution, you simply cannot create a safe implementation with only a single atomic counter - with incrementing before the insert, you have the possibility to read a value before it is fully written. And having done this myself, even different write and read indexes are insufficient to protect against ABA problems. Good luck

Okay, this has been very helpful and I've learned a lot to further understand the original implementation of ringbuffer-spsc and lock free ring buffers in general. Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.
